# Conditionally choose conda or singularity environment with Snakemake

Tags: conda, snakemake, hpc, singularity-container

I have what I hope is a simple question. I have been working on a Snakemake pipeline, for which I would like to add a config flag for if the pipeline should be run in "offline" mode. If in offline mode, each rule should use a singularity container, while in online mode, the a conda environment should be constructed for each rule. Is there a simple way to add a conditional that achieves this within a snakemake rule?

Something like:

```
rule NAME:
    input:
        "table.txt"
    output:
        "plots/myplot.pdf"
    # conditional environment selection
    if(flag):
        conda:
            "envs/ggplot.yaml"
    else:
        singularity: "env_ggplot.sif"
    script:
        "scripts/plot-stuff.R"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, both `conda:` and `singularity:` can accept `None` as an argument, so what I ended up doing is:

```py
    if config["offline"]:
        cnda = None
        sing = "env_ggplot.sif"
    else:
        cnda = "envs/ggplot.yaml"
        sing = None
```

Followed by

```py
    rule NAME:
        input:
            "table.txt",
        output:
            "plots/myplot.pdf",
        conda:
            cnda
        singularity:
            sing
        script:
            "scripts/plot-stuff.R"
```

Answer (score 0):

**(Option 1)**

`Snakefile`'s are Python files, so you can use `if-else` statements in the `Snakefile` and duplicate the rule:

```py
if config["use_conda"]:

    rule NAME:
        input:
            "table.txt",
        output:
            "plots/myplot.pdf",
        conda:
            "envs/ggplot.yaml"
        script:
            "scripts/plot-stuff.R"


elif config["use_singularity"]:

    rule NAME:
        input:
            "table.txt",
        output:
            "plots/myplot.pdf",
        singularity:
            "env_ggplot.sif"
        script:
            "scripts/plot-stuff.R"
```

This is relatively straigthforward and easy to understand if it is only for very few rules. As it creates code duplication it would become problematic for larger workflows.

**(Option 2)**

You could also try to set the environment programmatically by adding the following line at the end of your `Snakefile`. This code affects all rules, but you can modify it to only affect some rules (standard Python code):

```py
for r in workflow.rules:
    if config["use_conda"]:
        r.conda_env = "envs/ggplot.yaml"
```

Note that this is only the code for modifying the conda environment. There might be a singularity equivalent, but I don't know what is it and I couldn't find it either.

**(Option 3)**

My personal preference would be to handle it on a higher level and rather control which one is used using the snakemake flags instead of via the config file.
Use `--use-conda` or `--use-singularity` when calling `snakemake` depending on whether the pipeline should be run in online or offline mode. You could also define two snakemake profiles which include this difference.
Then specify both at the same time (untested by me):

```py
rule NAME:
    input:
        "table.txt",
    output:
        "plots/myplot.pdf",
    conda:
        "envs/ggplot.yaml"
    singularity:
        "env_ggplot.sif"
    script:
        "scripts/plot-stuff.R"
```